# Get test class names and test names from XCUITest

Tags: xcodebuild, names, xcuitest, uitest

I want to extract my test targets folder names, class names and test function names from each classes. I mean, I want to know all the test hierarchy so that I can create my own custom scheme before calling xcodebuild command.

Any suggestions?